# OpenCV 3.1 with Qt 5.6

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have got an issue while integrating opencv 3.1 with Qt 5.6. 
the project .pro file contains

```
    INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv/build/include
    LIBS += -LC:/opencv/build/x64/vc14/lib
    INCLUDEPATH += LIBS += -lopencv_world310
```

but gives undefined reference errors like:

```
    error: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture()
```

I have even tried using cmake, but it still gives the same error.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The second `INCLUDEPATH` looks totally borked. Remove that line, and replace it with `LIBS += -lopencv_world310`.

Comment: it is still the same

Comment: it still outputs the same error. 
but finally works using cmake-gui.

Comment: Just to be completely clear, as you have not specified those in your question: You are compiling for 64bit, using MS Visual Studio 2015 (or specifically the Visual C++ 14.0 compiler)?